# Type=cdir;Modify= message on joomla site

Tags: php, joomla

I have website on joomla 2.5. When I replaced it form local to host before every content I got this message:

```
Type=cdir;Modify=20161023020009;Unique=04c800920d9841c3;Perm=cmpdfe;
UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.owner=3155433;UNIX.group=1101; . Type=pdir;
Modify=20161023020009;Unique=04c800920d9841be;Perm=cmpdfe;UNIX.mode=0755;
UNIX.owner=3155433;UNIX.group=1101; .. Type=file;Size=5635;
Modify=20161023020007;Unique=04c800920d9841c4;Perm=adfrw;UNIX.mode=0644;
UNIX.owner=3155433;UNIX.group=1101; callback.php Type=file;Size=32;
Modify=20161023020007;Unique=04c800920d9841c5;Perm=adfrw;UNIX.mode=0644;
UNIX.owner=3155433;UNIX.group=1101; index.html Type=file;Size=2592;
Modify=20161023020008;Unique=04c800920d9841c6;Perm=adfrw;UNIX.mode=0644;
UNIX.owner=3155433;UNIX.group=1101; output.php Type=file;Size=4482;
Modify=20161023020008;Unique=04c800920d9841c7;Perm=adfrw;UNIX.mode=0644;
UNIX.owner=3155433;UNIX.group=1101; page.php Type=file;Size=3529;
Modify=20161023020009;Unique=04c800920d9841c8;Perm=adfrw;UNIX.mode=0644;
UNIX.owner=3155433;UNIX.group=1101; view.php
```

What should I do to remove it?

Comment: Turn on error reporting to development and see if there are any additional messages. Also if you have added and plugins, one at a time disable them and see which one may be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like output of MLSD command of FTP. You need to find the directory where you have files: callback.php, index.html, output.php, page.php, view.php and then investigate what extension/script are calling ftp command to list that directory.